# How to change version (dev-master) in packagist.org to version like v1.0.2?

Tags: php, git, github, packagist

I make repository in github. Register it in packagist.org
Set up in github integrations&services Packagist 
to track changes in repo.

In local comp I set this commands in console:
Add some changes, then add and commit it. 
Set tag like v1.0.2 :git tag v1.0.2 
and push it to github: git push origin v1.0.2

In github I create release https://github.com/sergwizard/maxmind-geolite2-db/releases

And I still see in packagist.org There is no license information available for the latest version (dev-master) of this package.

https://packagist.org/packages/sergwizard/maxmind-geolite2-db

How I can set versions instead (dev-master)?

Comment: Is your package on packagist updating automatically? I have a project on packagist that does not update itself when I push to GitHub. I have to manually click on the Update button, at the package page.

Comment: I set up automatic updates in github. But, if I update by pressing the button the version does not change.

Answer (score 3):

Just use local git commands:

```
git commit -a -m 'xxx'
git tag v1.0.2
git push origin v1.0.2
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem.
May bу someone will benefit from my experience. 
What I've done. I remowe one of my last releases and change one tag name in github repo. Then update my package in packagist by button "update" and bingo! Sow how pass versions beside dev-master.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the git push command doesn’t transfer tags to remote servers. You will have to explicitly push tags to a shared server after you have created them. This process is just like sharing remote branches — you can run:

```
git push origin <tagname>
```

Source: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging

Answer (score 0):

Just  do `git push origin v123` and wait 10 minutes. It always take some time for them.